# OSMNX: how to re-alive depreciated function "ox.distance.get_nearest_edge"?

Tags: python, attributeerror, osmnx

I have a VERY LONG script including the function "ox.distance.get_nearest_edge".
When I run it under my local computer with osmnx version 1.1.1, I get a warning that the function is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. I now need to let the script run on a server, I installed osmnx, but the script does'nt work anymore even though I installed the same version (1.1.1). (I also took care that python, geopandas, networkx etc were the same).

The error message I get is "AttributeError: 'osmnx.distance' has no attribute 'get_nearest_edge'"

(I tried to use the new function from osmnx instead (ox.distance.nearest_edges), but it seems to work very differently, and I run into errors trying to adapt my (long) script correcly).

Make old functions work would be a good way to keep old scripts working. But why is the funktion not becoming available again when I install the old osmnx-package with all of its dependencies? Do I have to install even older package versions of osmnx? I use anaconda package controlling, and JupyterLab to run my script (just in case that is a relevant detail).

Answer (score 1):

Re-verify the version you're running in your script. The `get_nearest_nodes` and `get_nearest_edges` functions were deprecated in v1.1 but not removed until the release of v1.2. If you do want to use a newer version, you can take advantage of the much faster and more flexible `nearest_nodes` and `nearest_edges` functions that replaced them. See the [docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.distance.nearest_edges) and usage [examples](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples) for details and demonstrations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attempt to help!!! The program version of osmnx I doubble-checked. It is, after a downgrade attempt, now even at v1.1.0 on the server where the script is supposed to run. I never had the latest version 1.2.1 installed on the server! I'm getting desperate because I now know for sure, thanks to your confirmation, that the get_nearest_edge function should keep working in 1.1.1.